# Vaadin datefield component set a default date

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7, datefield

My question is if I put a date field in my web application's UI using vaadin framework like following codes, then how can I set a default date value to it? I can also see the setValue() method suggestion coming with date field in eclipse editor but has not much information how to set a particular date with setValue() in its documentation.

```
DateField dueDate = new DateField();
dueDate.setDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
dueDate.setVisible(true);
dueDate.setCaption("Due Date");
**dueDate.setValue();**
```

Thanks in advance for your concerns. I am using vaadin7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's indeed the `setValue` method you need to call. You can supply a `java.util.Date` object. The first code example on [this documentation page](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-datefield.html) shows it.

```
// Create a DateField with the default style
DateField date = new DateField();

// Set the date and time to present
date.setValue(new Date());
```

If you are on Java 8 and want to use a `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime`, you need to convert it to `java.util.Date` or write a `Converter` for the `DateField` (I did that some time ago, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37236457/how-to-bind-a-vaadin-datefield-to-a-localdatetime)).